# Autofill for UITextField is broken

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autofill

In my sign up form in my app, the keyboard suggests an entry for my first name, last name, eventually a strong password, but not for my email address. I have content-type set to email in the storyboard and in code:

[image]

```
self.emailTxt.textContentType = .emailAddress
```

But no suggestion. You can see in the image below, the keyboard suggests the first and last name of the user, but for email it is blank. [image]

In the next image I show that in signing up for sites on safari, it does suggest my email. Even moreso, it suggests to autofill the entire page:[image]

What could I be missing?

### EDIT: I created a [github repo](https://github.com/PiedPieper/UITextFieldBug) demonstrating the error. Every field should be auto-filled. What I am experiencing is that in this app, the email works but password doesn't suggest to create a new password. Nothing is working together.

Comment: Are you running the app in the Simulator or on your device?

Comment: my device. Iphone XR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the issue in general was that apple's autofill was having a difficult time determining if I was creating an account. From their [documentation here:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)

> By default, the system selects the a keyboard based on the input
>   view’s textContentType property; however, you can mix the input view’s
>   text content type and keyboard type to explicitly define the desired
>   keyboard. For example, if your site uses email addresses as user
>   names, set the input view’s textContentType property to .username, and
>   set the keyboardType property to .UIKeyboardType.emailAddress.

So, for the email address I set the content type to username and the keyboard type to email, and all is fixed.

Comment: Perfekt  Works like charm

Comment: When I do that I get shown passwords instead of emails.

Comment: Could you please help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495065/how-to-enable-disable-onetimecode-feature-for-specific-text-field

Answer (score 0):

Setting Content-type =  {Email Address} works for me. It should work.

Try delete current UITextField and do it again

Comment: Just deleted the text field and reinserted... still not working