# Can an OTP code be read from Flash (Class 0) SMS message automatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, sms, one-time-password

I want to autofill a `UITextField` inside the app with an OTP code received inside a Flash SMS message. I know that it is possible to do this wit regular SMS messages, but I wonder if there is a way to achieve this using Flash SMS messages.

Comment: refer que and ans on this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61495271/12456741
kindly upvote it it helps ..

Comment: That does not help.